To evaluate constant in run time via function c++17
i have simple constant that i like to evaluate its value in run time ( or if you suggest better way ) .
inline float deg_to_rad(float p_y) {
    return p_y * static_cast<float>(Math_PI) / 180.f;
}

class TEST {  
    public: 
        const float _MOVEMENT_ = deg_to_rad(90);

}   

is there better way to do it ?

What's wrong with what you have now? The compiler is perfectly capable of computing the value at compile time, if that's what you are asking. In my example, int main() { return TEST{}._MOVEMENT_ * 10; } gets optimized down to return 15;

Unrelated, identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved. Don't use them in your code.

You could make the function constexpr and since _MOVEMENT_ is const and doesn't depend on any instance values, it could be made static constexpr. example

"i like to evaluate its value in run time..." Why? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? XY problem

You can't force a calculation to be run-time, if it could be done at compile time, because of the as-if rule.

Are you asking about some unit test library to verify code? Like gtest or Catch2? This class name TEST suggest something like that. Also you can use constexpr and static_assert C++ features.


Using a function doesn't require moving evaluation to runtime. Just add constexpr to the function and it will work at compile-time.

const float _MOVEMENT_ = deg_to_rad(90); will work even without a constexpr function, with the function you have right now.
But it is advisable to:

Make it static to share it across all instances of the class.

Make it constexpr (to make things easier)

Rename so that it doesn't use a reserved identifier (any identifier starting with _[A-Z] or containing __ is reserved).

Not name it in uppercase since it's not a macro (C/C++ uses uppercase for macros by convention, other languages tend to use it for constants since C macros often were used as constants, but it's weird IMO to make a full circle and use it for all constants in C/C++).
Same for the class name.


Overall, you end up with static constexpr movement = deg_to_rad(90);.


